# Prevent :after close-quote from wrapping into a new line

Tags: css

I'm using attempting to make a quote with `:before` open-quotes and `:after` close-quotes. The closing quotes are wrapping to a new line all by themselves in some instances. I'd like to make it so the last word and quotes break together, wrapping correctly. Any thoughts on how to do this in a way that would work across varying content? I'm using this in Drupal and this quote element is used in many articles with different content.

**CSS:**

```
p.quote {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-family: $didot-font;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 0;
  letter-spacing: 0.02px;
  line-height: 35px;
  color: $gray4-color;
  @extend %left-align;
  text-transform: none;
  font-style: italic;
  @extend %magin-position;

  &:before {
    content: open-quote;
  }
  &:after {
    content: close-quote;
  }
}
```

**Twig:**

```
<div class="col-12">
  <p class="quote" cite="">{{ content.field_quote }}</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trying adding the `display:inline-block;` to the elements. This will arrange them in one line.

You can also use `position: absolute;` then use the `top` and `left` properties.

Comment: Just adding display: inline-block doesn't quite do it. :( I've been toying with that and position properties all morning.

Comment: I've tried that as well and it is still not working. The " will still wrap to the next line all by itself.

Comment: Can you post the runnable code? So that its easy to edit it.

Comment: I figured out the issue. I was something in an additional twig file that was related to this one. Once I removed that additional twig, your suggestions worked! Thanks!

Comment: The absolute position is not an option on multiline quotes, because the quote would end up at the end of the first line horizontally. And the display: inline-block does not prevent wrapping. 

Any other options you all found out since this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the whitespace inside the handlebars tag is inserting whitespace between your quote elements and the text itself.  Run the following snippet and observe how the addition of whitespace before the end of the `<p>` element allows a word-break before the closing quote.

```css
.content {
  width: 600px;
}
.quote {
  background-color: #f0f0f0;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 400;
  padding: 2rem 2.5rem;
  letter-spacing: 0.02px;
  line-height: 35px;
  font-style: italic;
}

.quote:before {
  content: open-quote;
}
.quote:after {
  content: close-quote;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div class="content">
This one fits:
<p class="quote">This content should appear between quotes, and they are required to "stick" to the words, not wrap.</p>
This one is just a tiny bit wider:
<p class="quote">This content should appear between quotes, and quotes are required to stick to the words, not wrap.</p>
This one has LWS inside the &lt;p&gt; elements that separates the quotes from the text:
<p class="quote">
This content should appear between quotes, and quotes are required to stick to the words, not wrap.
</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```